# Add both client and server data in a Sencha 2 store

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have the following store:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.AdultMenuStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    fields: ['id', 'name','icon_url','xtype'],
    data: [
        {
            id:   'child1',
            name: 'Thomas',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-profile.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'addChild',
            name: 'Add child',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-plussign.png',
            xtype: 'addchildform'
        },{
            id:   'share',
            name: 'Share',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-shareicon.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'myProfile',
            name: 'My Profile',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-profile.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'help',
            name: 'Help',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-question.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        }]
}
});
```

I also want to add some json data from the server to this store, how can I contatinate client and server data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure, but you can use store's data property as follow:

```
storeObj.data.addAll(newData);
```

Assuming that `newData` is an array containing the server's share of data. But you need to take a look at ExtJS's API documentation. Sorry but setting up a test environment for this problem is time consuming and right now I don't have that much of it. I just hope I could point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a store with model you described above. The store should set proxy to server data

```
Store.load(function (store) {
    store.add(data)// data is an array with you local data
})
```